# Interpreting multiple interaction terms

Tags: econometrics, regression

I'm running the following regression on panel data:

$
%Translator MathMagic Pro for InDesign Mac v9.14, LaTeX converter, 2016.9.11 22:27
\begin{array}{l}
{{\mathrm{tscorek}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{0}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{1}{\mathrm{sck}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{2}{\mathrm{boy}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{3}{\mathrm{freelunk}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{4}{\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}}\\
{\hspace{1em}\hspace{1em}\hspace{1em}\hspace{1em}\hspace{1em}\hspace{1em}\>\>\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{5}\left({{\mathrm{boy}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{\cdot}{\mathrm{sck}}_{\mathrm{i}}}\right)\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{6}\left({{\mathrm{freelunk}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{\cdot}{\mathrm{sck}}_{\mathrm{i}}}\right)\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{7}\left({{\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{\times}{\mathrm{sck}}_{\mathrm{i}}}\right)\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\varepsilon}}_{\mathrm{i}}}
\end{array}
%MathMagic MMF.7h]a5`00]EQ]Km|f4?h5n*on:0):`N);B?FKhkZY|LP)K3GM(?N3VkRM|M*)57M[E^*_k3N?Ae7BbK:U0)fZ*^K3)o8N?CbNZ2`WdcNcNC9(9k?YfONciFPn7ZJcNI2|mWlTZlnKfmie]^]mfVFmbOKenW7cNM];E[Nm_n81b?kI(YfTEn?PCKKkD]UOmM9[j6Go?^bfSn_7LlH7VngMWGFn6LlG=TbP`aj4?FIkGPoCLA1KJ35W4=TkOlGe:aKeTDZP;[Vnn1=ndfl]OSnIG|e6PF1a2(b4QT(8(T;?lJoGEl?9=)RO?InM;AOS=9e(;o5Y5X_Y(1T7bE)fFMgI20mkjofh3eSX^o3Q9W];9_AGKXL))nn`Rc19E[g;K;gnLk5XF6F[EGG(7A5k`jSKS2HLkKiVVgGF|(AQ|]^^KY]3X5)Y;ZVPBb]X5`_JeH8^^J1E;fPE34h[1RLUhefBlLk|jY:(]d_6fbGSGI;aE|UhZfCl]6ClY6C2BYJ(e]_menaY^_jkJHL))nn`Rc0lk9;=;]G||TXThoe]LdImbV2)6_ja9HN7g;M]h*ZEKg?K5RY_Ra1;VPOB0^fM51Zh=dAXl6e=IS;X57UPJfAXRW3(PWcd*h1]USNA1^A=CSb*QAZH720;hOfAANbMT0Ch][J?aPHb1lH1T*=T0DDdEW9m`;9AdK3253`0PdN5*I8PP=6iKf?dXUlkYf:84h4E::K()2=|)270lNWS0PPBU5(6G94Q4Ie;EgBhOoh2DPD49B20b26LoPD*iMXmH9jB(LQ038C`lPZRPm14)F7Xi341TUE39=50L]8FY4dET7UlGD0(Oej*TgTJR29aT88Y?6?bO8ZA:AD*=hDTo7Q5ed59C951PAAMI)FFX|aAI)7CA1WBSZ|TRaQY4`dR3)nC9A:ECY6;GSPY2R8b4bj0:7Q4a^fX0|EE54ggPJIIX7TEDi(ed=8YZceBM4Q4mZLVNJQ=mBcJ9J4G`V1hhNLb=;c9Tk10PYXTFCnS71dOb4*EDJ=Y*QQ3;7*Oa2*7Hj9oc4W8F5CBaY;TMZcXE14MXTW:a8H2VWlfLk225Pl03)Z*k0AP90f0B*XDMJ?U09R^8ELA2T3B481A8J5F4h6CHP^^;9j;dRQ[E*hX5HPXd:6|02YbGTiITlCEaW;]`EG7X]RjlUP2DKddP5=1G7WT9J8;0ji2VQ:Aa01)]PH8nWIb5K;(9Q1TMh2]TJabM=UI(7A5DYJZR][B24eYeLXT^3XYbgL?:eo(R804UfFe_QaN1oR)MhlG2_^KXi`KF|6Q^]ENg|ZMcME3lP_N:^`X79N?cno6eDNdBV_12be)SAakZjZ)(_Cbe|Ra)(E:UeK][;YV=JeShgHe)|C:Wo?`RZei?Y^U0A|`^bafa`Rlfk()_VlHgYUKaBnOP_Y9(^n38ggTa3Rk_g=7iM`PSSS;Dlkf99d(|fcWoO2dN;7I[[:W7)(QLK[n_=Z_LhaW`oWjO[GOk;IiScdB9cL[Ni[nN;oVWRg;Ci0N8OWa]gfflYRC4D?O9dSOQNnCY6oTnaCYNngkXV)2jF)MiY*:n2gD59RML|O_7jXJO^kDI7)O=e*gmd5C5hj[YW8lX|YaGEN)VjIb?6hZici63YAc7b07bQelM?S)HnTSC^J?D(OLXi?^^ZjLnmRPbXWh*3W96|Y9J2XW)EE)R[YbDSJETjZYW8bJbTUmX=cZg^hJ?);J137^_gGa`;JIJc_TC[V[[)H^|M|E1Nb*gU?R9=IiM3Fg1F2jbkj|kW_Yn]_N5lKlPP5cYOGR5nMWFh]gBH0:C:IYP(4FKfO_;hJ;|C?NS4O3dBS04M?I^m7=d8g1?c2=I]=d?4ga3d`9U_onmnG5kf7a3cilGhj2oN?];[?[]Tc]5S_V|)To?blGMUOY__daL=ZCiIi2Vbi?*(mAl7SK7OL5|o5l]XnkYilaVlQWnfBcnOk[mZL*U6i:k=GH:L(?`GjgGgmk)3ekcATS?Anj;)cK|Mmm1jQnG|9E8EOk1[(_j2?FUfQ|Cd[mUbc^lo;6RVe_EYjGLH]J^KehaOhoP[Z=h8n]_hd|8oT3_1E[8Nj6?M^RlAme1Fdf.mmf
$

Where every variable is a dummy except for the dependant variable and totexpk. I'm having trouble with interpreting the coefficients of this regression; the way I see it, it's very complicated to put them into words:

$
%Translator MathMagic Pro for InDesign Mac v9.14, AMS LaTeX converter, 2016.9.11 22:30
\begin{gathered}
{{\mathbb{E}}\left({{{\mathrm{tscorek}}_{\mathrm{i}}}\vert{{\mathrm{sck}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{1}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{boy}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{1}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{freelunk}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{1}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}}}\right)\hspace{1em}\mathrm{{=}}\hspace{1em}\left({{\mathrm{\beta}}_{0}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{1}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{2}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{3}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{5}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{6}}\right)\mathrm{{+}}\left({{\mathrm{\beta}}_{4}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{7}}\right){\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}} \hfill\\
{{\mathbb{E}}\left({{{\mathrm{tscorek}}_{\mathrm{i}}}\vert{{\mathrm{sck}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{1}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{boy}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{1}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{freelunk}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{0}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}}}\right)\hspace{1em}\mathrm{{=}}\hspace{1em}\left({{\mathrm{\beta}}_{0}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{1}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{2}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{5}}\right)\mathrm{{+}}\left({{\mathrm{\beta}}_{4}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{7}}\right){\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}} \hfill\\
{{\mathbb{E}}\left({{{\mathrm{tscorek}}_{\mathrm{i}}}\vert{{\mathrm{sck}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{1}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{boy}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{0}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{freelunk}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{1}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}}}\right)\hspace{1em}\mathrm{{=}}\hspace{1em}\left({{\mathrm{\beta}}_{0}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{1}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{3}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{6}}\right)\mathrm{{+}}\left({{\mathrm{\beta}}_{4}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{7}}\right){\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}} \hfill
\end{gathered}
%MathMagic MMF.7h]G7*00kEQAKm|f4?h5n*mnU075h96D:?G=LMgDF6*7]YY^V?^P9ViW=;D3aMfJ5OT;nlgSTIAd|R`[Fihf90Y|O[`kg_7SlDQi)IVnVLfCHCZICDmnW2a7lo4`WLfm9=_mUVBOemNmbgcKnkC=Ni?=jmGmn_)VUfCG_MoS0LSnbC:MY1MSkdfnoE[9GoGBBnSUOme]=oN[ne?61n_=cHeF_Q[?5mZ=Yo`Nn3fVNeh?dk4GJjPaIa3ZCoi:|5N0`]7L2lji)_|2_jRg6[nOC2mV8dl6h4?4OF0Ald4:YDGSWbl_QY)Yecmi?3UI;|IY)YVNhg*FRnT`6G_9*kk)K[B;^igF_]mic7MM);_9CTOS^lO:XD?))nC2Ci:|Mij_EUlFRhID7YD67F)7A=h*ZV?2b1m]_nG[EMj*a7jbgFCGCA?XI:Z;:^SR2XjC1LOIPRjjh2QOL9*`J6L(FRWSGICac^cZXX`OYh`OYhagDLJ?D|J?D|KK:N)]U0U=FC9JKGKOlXOYjXnV73[T_4(^O7noBcJkPVJGIR8IkjjK8jXf*GA*l:L^)McW[Zd[V1nh]ZiT_PQ|FnPfB0NT1|XY1BSPCQ2R`;DE6BU2YM21F8)XL:L;YFn]kca|(m_4((0f)M70:891I0568I`nAQ4k9*`2G5_YZK61]20b*5R0DD3QSIFagV7IZ(;*a1Aa03X?2h4TCP2mLmM6kdFo(TZ5RB615BRVTG56X^4T08jcS`|PR5=)8n01(*WYF:X:Qk_i5i0b86P00PPM`_1O056^gAgV:K712(A024N_83`8AIPC4Adl9T2bbT*B3R*WKD7JU05YoJ|2X__C8SQYdd0DRH(QA8EVC)HG(38TW^JUFX11)?^0[T(P(DD61*[X8PMV:LXLaBQLVP*AJLMETXF(]0T78KYgbA::RZO*N2nD0PY2(Q8^P2SR22)cX`XDEehDg*N:IX7RUDm5eT19`jab::0V8MVOR^BQRZZi:9)4SPRl=OW2SAEAmi5=`P89:Y9ToJ;0Q)(LAF4EJ:AX*T*ATM1m49(LS0Wo(BL^He5A6d^Bfg50Q`ZYRB8Y4dLDd?cCVH(E]9P0(:Q3|Q)0TC*09RT8Z1X]1l1D3IV:D02BQP2(4PVeVPRL55|`IO5DU49IZg90*h6*0^G;2R0SYnF*=DY(KBcG7Tae;8Z]:HlU4=FQ0I`BH|XS;a5M630E(RXAB*cPI6^0X:NCZI1U=X4P^`=dSFBEX|W)8T9C96G9ZZP]SE0d[5ZI15(WIGWf|?9PAPC4^Bb[mOW`d|(cgTc?5o[K8Q|KB|6P^U*oC|Z=c=A3lPe):[*EfUUknaVInXQBZBGhX(B`HK6C1]EEQSi)6YXXfZ9BYE*IZJY9Xj)flG4f)|RblmaoHRfNcfJYa`I(;h_N(*8omEd7ca^6Wlb|h]M?G_dVJO_P*1ni(Li^KlaEf*[40FGIYZa_d|T`ckM)3fn;In]=USmHS9O4jNYc]U]IS7O3nNXffjfg6m^S[lC9EJI_dam_Ema5bn`=dR4(O_amUfL)Lf8aM7f2m9fi?TWjAZh_87f_GEmhR31eZ3=ZH`7OQIX4|cIeO?nQ[)7[CXdflgY3NC(_=7GRN=1TSXND)JkZc?6XbAb?VlbIUi4mi|`;b1icNblM[_=*nXSFo1718OF`EEgEVC(_6i*i4Nla9eV3)*U=iRBWc4UAIdk:9W(bJ38W`bIcD^daUmgZGH=GG9dPTOWG:PkX=S=]Pl`]=l][jQ:kCE703^Td9*jRUDLGLed0Y]_lJgKKBeOOMjh`fPL6c9CF|in(WVh]gRDN(S2IYQhjFkbM_ClK;|I6N3DN3DLS3bfV|gNSZj6a`AnHA[=Y)YjVn0=CP^Foof=imZ]Oo(677l|A*Wc[e7lO_75oZF^G;|d=_AC[m05cKgMo_Lge|V|=20lY[?^?Sho=k__[3Y_U*VmTeEoRa9H;;;WHG_X4O=`n?7^(CcYYKkm]WQd(FRTdTY[7gGJgnWkG?VI=fA9dYJ];ggb;__j*oDLL)^`GWReXFIf5_QngCh3I2*PEmC|dhLVJo(VJh|VJ`I(e*dMIAIFenUOdb2NkEO]^WkgZ;k_aNK^A_Nc6OkHKPiNMlioN)Fd9og:)DLfWkibWWdkoUc?WDMl(o`IYR]*7.mmf
$
$
%Translator MathMagic Pro for InDesign Mac v9.14, AMS LaTeX converter, 2016.9.11 22:31
\begin{gathered}
{{\mathbb{E}}\left({{{\mathrm{tscorek}}_{\mathrm{i}}}\vert{{\mathrm{sck}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{1}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{boy}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{0}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{freelunk}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{0}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}}}\right)\hspace{1em}\mathrm{{=}}\hspace{1em}\left({{\mathrm{\beta}}_{0}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{1}}\right)\mathrm{{+}}\left({{\mathrm{\beta}}_{4}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{7}}\right){\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}} \hfill\\
{{\mathbb{E}}\left({{{\mathrm{tscorek}}_{\mathrm{i}}}\vert{{\mathrm{sck}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{0}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{boy}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{1}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{freelunk}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{1}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}}}\right)\hspace{1em}\mathrm{{=}}\hspace{1em}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{0}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{2}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{3}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{4}{\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}} \hfill\\
{{\mathbb{E}}\left({{{\mathrm{tscorek}}_{\mathrm{i}}}\vert{{\mathrm{sck}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{0}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{boy}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{1}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{freelunk}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{0}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}}}\right)\hspace{1em}\mathrm{{=}}\hspace{1em}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{0}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{2}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{4}{\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}} \hfill\\
{{\mathbb{E}}\left({{{\mathrm{tscorek}}_{\mathrm{i}}}\vert{{\mathrm{sck}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{0}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{boy}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{0}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{freelunk}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{1}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}}}\right)\hspace{1em}\mathrm{{=}}\hspace{1em}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{0}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{3}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{4}{\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}} \hfill\\
{{\mathbb{E}}\left({{{\mathrm{tscorek}}_{\mathrm{i}}}\vert{{\mathrm{sck}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{0}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{boy}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{0}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{freelunk}}_{\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{{=}}{0}\>{\mathrm{,}}\>{\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}}}\right)\hspace{1em}\mathrm{{=}}\hspace{1em}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{0}\mathrm{{+}}{\mathrm{\beta}}_{4}{\mathrm{totexpk}}_{\mathrm{i}}} \hfill
\end{gathered}
%MathMagic MMF.7h|C8000kESQK]|f47j2_8=obX1Rl4Q:Y?[?LMgDF6*7|IY^V?]3CMc)F6X7R[|e:o8:NnKa:4XjFIJEKTFk5Xd2VmoMTGOlN3bAGTbVcfHGlC2Ic:I77hlFXh_a(9UMN76joBe)gjj^N^OIY_MVToDVjjO;^mGKMBm)[gYoA0)*oJ=5(TW)a]jcK?)^dSoY9NO*bojngJc_UWO7S0mFjn][Hg`i_YPK=ikbNn3gV94l7BIS;c;*H(hP=9olRH0W;)aS:5i`b]G9ko2;NVk`blWdK3KbI00nJ)h3dl`7:IAASGln?a])YUkoj)7XJ34O9lUTNX[CVLnW`gS|aOOI:[df;Vjga_Y^jc7ORG1fTjf9aWM?[XL)?No*2cn)dmiY]Ucn?Ylg]?:P=^PH)bCjQU8MDVYo]7VO[III*a?ilFJMGSFk*2MCGEA15eM`V2`hc1Idd*D7nH:3Q44kHm1:6NnRS7MVEaMUo31Uo31U_8|bOY0bOY0bgThIKjE(6([RdG:mOIoMCiMo=_G*XNLMN^7k^b;I50E=TF4R7Vn_VR)Z=XGNZoS;U1c^LmLf5L`?G=]D(Ul4NE^H=TP7Y07:6*FXh4hAX|:e5AU9Xe7X*6B0;]bI*^WW_FlmK;)lRF50g^C40Z(81SX768E`mQQ5i8``271]IJK61S87fP:A0h`22Vn|S?DFbdHEQR6VR0?*NEPX9742j9fk=WX_i(XJ5Ed|2Ja04Hf((a8=9`5`W7eD046LLQX13dRGT8jUZW2hVgl1:*)21R20d24|o`D*iM[MHYjB?QR160SQj1F41j48Ld;C`B(29:^jB(:1i:*]B9|b87?oZX3Xo[P8C^IY88[4`A1dHAVAn*F(38U_lm8|`21Loh2^*b0aA*H52^PR1gHYbQc5:5bJ19ZdXb[9*TKJQ8(*gK]T2DG5DfRm5dH11B4I2AM05764f^jX0TFE5dGgPJ9IX7SUDi4eD=8bZa`:J9N*k4m5lU3YJRk:9Z4S0Tm=_W1SJNYNidUH845ETZbO3V`hcY4)Zd2eXPVQ=M7*OA2A78`8oa4W;R=ADA]9T]]A*8L:JAM5DRKB5=3l(iV35KBH032X*k8CP94d02HY2:PI;*O0E0gIRU00TXH0S189]IX8W1AK|6GaF9A:FJ]b*4)1T0;Ub`XP8lOUT3E:K6d|eai|MBb:[Bf?9A3EB`(h9LBFAehR^S1P:j*^4DT(h6A[P:1_9e|Qbf`2*GH7V1[9:T)KWDF4]TS:TUEAFaZQJ5Re(PVfC|[bgL?:5c(R8(iUFJe?QnLN_^?]m7aQ_W)DahIJ|:R^=HoCLZ^cmI1lPm(:d`_kiOgcCfg[8fZUdN236|]6SYdfZ8hbm77Jd4KA5YDZ]LYZEDf[3oJ=3[?A*EHncmdW(^Z;fBcaf82IIC4kA^2W)N_PnhKQ9k)[n)j=Ecm9iS;H8b(Wa]W=]CdZi`ZaaeRf6I^CM3c(|Xfc`m?RbFZMI_LiaT?RM?TfgBicS6O3RnE=^Ue]e[W478WSbmBLYUoO;;V;U^DWB8L`n?67KIHjc4V?XI(98S]a(TUT8bL;R)bYThGk25?kQ;Z=1K`;=*UVKNIhoj6|hGFWAY^mgU3Nk8FVCQ`?V|caT3;7EIdi[Y_(lJS9W;f(k31W;b0kc)eL)Ya`GoZ8e_`A`Ckc|=ELeIVcU`g:W8QfV9)|`Ib49W)BDnJTZ3(WII(i6CBITf6C)JUfV4]_c:k18ji946goSHT3Y|e|fb9kbTfcV[U4|Bd::93)D^8PaWQdMV4:`7BC_D]_N|Wb`mHEa_b10K)UmN*WJfMJlaNaQ`a(YXV7c^K?Ibm?Q_)aEEj)Al?Ab((NdmV;dNG*m|4OV4JcJC:N9_P3DhcU_omaLO:[Goc1Zhn;4D:lMIZoEmjh_c2ebiCVQUf2MGY?MfmkMkG9c;8K2`Sg6Jcj3`l?CO7MEDNOaMa|I=EOh(*FLbbif5kh1;cNg3mf3=HfaQ^C]3O_ehl)YVdPk:F`Tc*lKSOKiHOKmS5[aSU1UjJjm)fgj9|?fGo0XL=nhCT7;J|c=nOSmPV`O092jGj79KQ*ZQ3bG_o:[GbdFkG[mSncn*eVNF^6OT:F]njDClgb]X6nC9Io[WCVSkHDSkJdFOdS?kmbOWkM:_cUlo=7e_dOg_gOAeGlDN^n[Jck?V[MIlVU1g)[n*LABXSj.mmf
$

Is there some interpretation-friendly way to interpret the coefficients that I'm missing here?

Comment: Think average differences between groups.